# Need to remove blogger image from posts

Tags: blogger

I am using a custom blogger template but there is this unwanted blogger logo and its surrounding space which I am unable to remove. Can you please help ?

Thanks in advance.

Screenshot

[image: xxxx]

[Sample page on my blog](http://www.moneyplanters.com/2014/10/5-mistakes-youll-never-make-again.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your blog dashboard, Click **Theme** > **Customize** > **Advanced** > **Add CSS** paste the next code and click **Apply to Blog**

```
.about-author { display: none; }
.related-post { padding: 0; }
```